# Changin format of the number in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Need to change format of the numbers from 7500,00 to 7.500,00
Changing the custom number format doesn't help ass it recognize the dot only for the decimal separator but in my case
dot - thousands separator
coma - decimal separator

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Default number formatting depends on **File > Settings > Locale**. Use a locale where **Format > Number > Number** gets the format you want, or alternatively, use this custom number format:

`#"."##0.00`